# Is it possible to enable the users of my iPhone app to download and have access to images I display in my app?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, local-storage, share

I have a simple image viewing iPhone app, and I would like to give users of the app access to the image content if they want to share it with their friends. Is it possible to somehow enable them to save the image to their device image folder? I haven't really used the iPhone much so I am not familiar with standard functionality, but if it were possible, I'd love to hear any ideas about how it might be done. All of the images I present are just sitting in the app resource folder.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function to save your image(s) in the user's camera roll. Obviously you would write some code giving them the option to do this or cancel :)